# Where is the data in the InputStream returned by HttpURLConnection stored before you read it?

Tags: java, android, http, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm writing an android app that uses [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to download some data.  The [getInputStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) method returns an InputStream that I can read the data from.  Where is the data stored before I read from this stream?  Is it all downloaded and the network stack is taking care of holding on to it?  Or could there still be data that needs to be retrieved from the server?  Can I close the connection and still read from the InputStream?  My question is in terms of performance and doing something responsible in the event that the data is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the data stored before I read from this stream?

(I don't know. You have to read the source code.)

> Is it all downloaded and the network stack is taking care of holding on to it?

No, it is a stream. Data arrives in a byte stream and you can read from the stream.

> Or could there still be data that needs to be retrieved from the server?

Yes, this is the normal case, especially when the payload weights more than a few kilobytes.

> Can I close the connection and still read from the InputStream?

Short answer: No.

You mean calling `disconnect()` from `HttpURLConnection`? Not sure if it' s possible but I wouldn't do that. It indicates that you don't want to make subsequent requests in the near future. This could imply that the connections will be closed physically.

Or do you mean calling `InputStream.close()`? I'm quite sure that you'll get some kind of `IllegalStateException` or `IOException` when you try to read from a closed stream.

---

Generally `HttpURLConnection` is a good choice for your app. If you encounter any problems, you can have a look at this (incomplete) [list of libraries and helpers](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background) you can use to make your life easier when doing HTTP requests on Android. And maybe you can leverage the [android.app.DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).